# Flash Builder 4 not finding classes, autocomplete not working

Tags: actionscript-3, autocomplete, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

For some reason Flash Builder 4 doesn't autocomplete any more for new projects I create (either pure Actionscript or Flash Pro projects). But for previous projects it still works fine.

For instance when I go to create a new actionscript class, when I click browse next to Superclass there are only TWO classes that come up. EventDispatcher & Sprite. Where have the rest of the classes gone?

When I try to type inside the class.. ie var mc:MovieClip... as I'm typing MovieClip nothing comes up any more.. pushing ctrl+space doesn't bring up a list of classes either. Importing classes, no code hinting comes up at all.

I haven't changed anything in Flash Builder between now and when my previous projects were created.

Any help much appreciated!!! Deadlines looming, no autocomplete = massive pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I solved this by simply uninstalling and installing Flash Builder...

Obviously a bug in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem happen to me and It was due to my project being created in a directory that was within the directory of an existing project directory. Once I moved my new project to a directory higher than and separate from the other projects it all worked fine. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Mine was similar to this in that it was related to nested projects (I think someone was goofing around with the repo), but I had a src folder an additional tier down from the main project.  I had originally thought autocomplete worked on any actionscript files in a project tree, apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I added the `-advanced-telemetry` compiler option in Flash Builder 4.7 using the Apache 4.10 SDK.  It's supported by the SDK but not by Flash Builder apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new workspace

```
File > Switch Workspace > Other
```

Then select a new directory for the workspace.

I'm actually having the opposite problem - new projects work, and my existing project doesn't work. This didn't fix that problem - but may fix the opposite problem. Certainly better then uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, I found auto-complete to be very inconsistent when I type command-space (sometimes the dropdown would appear after two or three times in a row hitting command-space, sometimes never), but always comes up when I type control-space.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewforum.php?f=11) !!

[Comparison with FlashBuilder](http://cameronellis.posterous.com/flex-4-vs-flashdevelop-3)

My intellisense worked instantly, and my Flex project file worked too (didn't need to reimport all the times).